# Count and return where 2 fields match

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to write a script that counts results based on 2 fields matching - but not matching like identically, but where the values re-occur throughout the table.

For example, I want to find where Field A and Field B = x & y, respectively (and count those results) however, field A isn't always X and field B isn't always Y.  Also, Field A and Field B values are unknown.  Here's what I've written so far:

```
select a.fielda, b.fieldb, count (*)
from tableA a
join tableB b
on a.fieldd = b.fieldd

where a.fielda = b.fieldb --I know this is a problem, just for notes on what I'm trying to accomplish.
group by b.fieldb, a.fielda
order by b.fieldb.
```

I'm a newb here so any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would make this much clearer.

Comment: Just remove the `where a.fielda = b.fieldb`line altogether. What's left should be the correct query based on what you've described.

Comment: Tobsey, you were right.  I didn't think that by selecting those two fields, I was already finding records where those values were the same.  THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tobsey had it correct for me.  I didn't think that by selecting the two fields that I was already finding records where those two fields existed together...brain fart, I guess.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.fielda = b.fieldb THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MatchCount
     , SUM(CASE WHEN a.fielda = x and b.fieldb = y THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS XYCount
     , COUNT(*) AS FieldDMatchCount
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
  ON a.fieldd = b.fieldd
```